# Pandas selecting data with specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
item    storage
record  paper
record  laptop
record  desktop
file    laptop
file    paper
file    paper
record  desktop
file    desktop
```

If I want a new data frame with 2 criteria such as 'record' in the item column and 'laptop' or desktop in the storage column is there an easier way to select this dataset rather than:

```
df1=df[(df['item'] == 'record') &  (df['storage'] == 'laptop')]
df2=df[(df['item'] == 'record') &  (df['storage'] == 'desktop')]
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Is there a shorter way to do this something in one line like:

```
df3=df[(df['item'] == 'record') &  (df['storage'] == 'laptop' or 'desktop')] #This does not work
```

Comment: `df['storage'] in ('laptop', 'desktop')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change one of the conditions to `.isin`:

```
>>> df['storage'].isin(['laptop', 'desktop'])
```

so:

```
>>> df[(df['item'] == 'record') & (df['storage'].isin(['laptop', 'desktop']))]
     item  storage
1  record   laptop
2  record  desktop
6  record  desktop
```

Comment: You edited your answer quicker than I could post mine which was identical to yours ;)